# How can I update Lumen via composer?

Tags: queue, composer-php, lumen

I'm developping a web app using Lumen. I followed the instructions from the doc, installing `laravel/lumen-installer` via Composer, then doing `lumen new myApp` to get it properly installed (it was in April 2015).

While working on queues, the method "onQueue" was (and still is) not found... I presume I have an old version of the package "Illuminate/queue" (or what else?). Checking on packagist, Lumen is now in **v5.1.5** (https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/lumen-framework) and the one I'm using is **v5.0.4**. So I did an update with composer :

```
composer update laravel/lumen-framework
```

But I get the **v5.0.10**, not the 5.1.4. Why so?

I checked that issue: https://github.com/dingo/api/issues/447 but in my composer.json, I have:

```
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
```

So what is the problem? How can I get the last version of Lumen? Moreover, how can I get the onQueue method (updating only the package "Illuminate/queue")?

Thanks in advance

---

**UPDATE**, as asked in comments below, this is my initial `composer.json` (just not to miss anything):

```
{
    "require": {
        "laravel/lumen-installer": "~1.0"
    }
}
```

and myApp composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/lumen",
    "description": "The Laravel Lumen Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel", "lumen"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "laravel/lumen-framework": "5.0.*",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "~1.0",
        "illuminate/mail": "~5.0",
        "imagine/imagine": "^0.6.2",
        "league/csv": "^7.1",
        "gregwar/captcha": "^1.1",
        "neitanod/forceutf8": "^1.4",
        "predis/predis": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your full `composer.json` file.

Comment: By far the easiest way is to run `composer require laravel/lumen-framework:5.1` which will update your composer.json and include the new dependency. This is easier than the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update your composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/lumen-framework": "5.1.*",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "~1.0"
},
```

Comment: and then running `composer update laravel/lumen-framework`?

Comment: With just one composer update. But then would have to follow the upgrade guide because things have changed

Comment: You _really_ only need to change the `"laravel/lumen-framework": "5.1.*"` line. If you want to always have the most recent update to version 5, then you should have `"laravel/lumen-framework": "~5.1"`.

Comment: OK, I did it... every dependencies were updated... and BOOM! no way to get my homepage. I tried a `die('reached line #'.__line__);` in the `app.php`, and everything works fine, except the final `$app->run();`... I'm reinstalling everything from scratch now!

Comment: Replace $app->run(); for $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture();
$app->run($request); in your index.php

Comment: Laravel (and Lumen) are NOT following Semver, so using `~5.1` would be asking for trouble.